# where are validation messages coming from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a newly created MVC project, in the Account Register page, if I don't fill in any information and click Register button, I will see

> •The User name field is required.
>
> •The Password field is required.

Where are these coming from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual message string is stored in a `MvcHtmlString` object in `System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.`  It is the return value on the `ValidationExtensions` method called by the `ValidationMessageFor()` helper method that is invoked in the view.

Comment: Oh thank you, I see it it now, but now I would like to delete the word `"field"` in that message ? How can I do that ?

Comment: You cannot change the default message, but you can override it with your own.  In the Model just specify the message you want to show: `[Required(ErrorMessage = "The User name is required")]`

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the Register ActionResult (in AccountController.cs)

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) // here it will check it lal
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

You see the ModelState.IsValid, basicly it checks or the model has any validations issues.

The model can be found in AccountModels

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see they both got a require tag so they will return false and display next to it that it is required (when it is not filled in)

EDIT: 
Since you want to know why it is that text and not some other text, it is the default text so ask microsoft :), anyway you can modify the text as you like by adding the ErrorMessage parameter to the Required tag.

Example:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Hey you forgot me!")]
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it is from the `[Required]`, I'd like to know where those text messages are stored.

Comment: @BéVúSữa1 look at the HTML. You'll see the messages there for the unobtrusive javascript validation.

Comment: I ask the question because I think at least I could find the string `The + [name-of-control]+ field is required` but I couldn't find it anywhere in the js files

Comment: @BéVúSữa1 the default message doesn't show up in the Model code, but as the accepted answer says, you can set it to whatever you want. Also, the message is not in the js file but in a `data-` attribute of the field if you look at the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

look in the assiciated model for [required] at the top.